# How to use mongodb query in hibernate OGM?

Tags: mongodb, hibernate-ogm

**I want to find only the username field in my Registration collection**

I am using the following query

```
db.Registration.find( {"username":"abcd"},  {username:1, _id:0} )
```

How will I write this query in hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

If your entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
class Registration {
  @Id
  String id;

  String username:
}
```

This should work:

```
String query = "FROM Registration r WHERE r.username = :username ORDER by r.username ASC, r.id DESC"
List<Registration> results = entityManager.createQuery( query )
                               .setParameter("username", "abcd")
                               .getResultList()
```

or

```
Registration results = entityManager.createQuery( query )
                               .setParameter("username", "abcd")
                               .getSingleResult()
```

You can also use native queries but I will let you to the documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/ogm/5.4/reference/en-US/html_single/#ogm-mongodb-queries-native

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to annotate the (none PK) columns you want to retrieve in the Entity with:

```
@Column(name = "username")
```

Comment: That's not true. You only need that if the name of the property is not "username". Properties are queryable fields by default (unless you make them transient).